# Excel - Compare arrays and specify which columns to compare until the first column is blank

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am looking to compare 2 arrays in the same sheet row by row, but would like to specify which column in array 1 should be compared to which column in array 2 and do this until the value is column A is blank. For example array 1 is A:E and array 2 is G:L and I would like to compare column B to the values in column G and say column A will be compared with values in column L.

What is the best way to do this and how can I stop when the value is blank for the row I'm comparing in column A when I'm comparing columns B and G?

At the moment it looks like I will need to loop through each column in turn which would mean about 5 separate loops like below.

```
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String)
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Range("L:L")
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Range("A:A").Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Range("G:G")    
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Range("B:B").Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If  
Next

'Repeated 3 more times.....

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String)
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim mydiffs As Integer
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim mycell As Range

For Each strArray In Array("L/A", "G/B")
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore)
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Split(strArray, "/")(0)).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each mycell In .Range(Split(strArray, "/")(0) & "1:" & Split(strArray, "/")(0) & lngLastRow)
            If Not mycell.Value = .Range(Split(strArray, "/")(1) & mycell.Row).Value Then
                mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next strArray

End Sub
```

Obviously, you can extend upon the array to include additional columns to compare to one another. L/A stands for: compare column L to column A, where column L (the first column) dictates how many rows will be compared (until there are no more in column L even though there still might be some more in column A).

Note, you could optimize the code by using `.Value2` instead of `.Value` if that's an option.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Using the code above, it looks like it is comparing column L against column L.  Is that correct and I need to modify it or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Works great.  Thanks again.